# c++ typename in vc++ and clang

Tags: c++, using, typename

The following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    using TT = typename T;

};
```

vc++ is ok. clang outputs: error: expected a qualified name after 
'typename' using TT = typename T; .

If you change

```
using TT = typename T;
```

to

```
using TT = T;
```

,vc++ and clang are ok.

why?

Comment: It's not standard to put typename T after, it should just be the variable name at that point.

Comment: By the time the compiler reaches the line `using TT = typename T`, it already knows what T is. `typename T` is required, when the compiler doesn't know that `T` is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect C++.  The C++ grammar specifies that the keyword `typename` (besides its other use to declare a template parameter) may only be used at the beginning of a *qualified-id*, which is a name that includes at least one `::` token.

Apparently MSVC allows a more generous syntax here.

(`typename` **must** be used in most contexts within a template whenever the *qualified-id* is a dependent name that is supposed to be a type, not a variable or a template.  Here "dependent name" roughly means that the compiler can't be sure of finding a declaration for it, due to depending on template parameters.  But it's also valid to use the keyword on a *qualified-id* that is not dependent, or not in a template at all.)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler already knows that `T` is a type name because you declared it in class template, so you should `using TT = T` instead of `using TT = typename T`.
VC++ does not follow all ISO standard, so some code that failed to compile in gcc or clang may work in VC++